# Change Background image of particular Carousel indicator in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, carousel

I am Working with Sencha touch application.

I have create Carousel like view with swipe using Ext.Carousel Component it shows default carousel indicators at bottom, also i can change background image and color for all the carousel indicators.

But, now i want to set background image on only first carousel indicator and want remain all others indicators by default.

can anyone help for this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target it with CSS using the `:first-child` selector:

```
.x-carousel-indicator span:first-child {
    // custom styling
}
```